# Sharing Git Submodules

Tags: git, version-control, dependencies, git-submodules

I have Libraries A, B, C, and D.

the dependencies look like so:

```
   A
   |
  / \
B     C
 \   /
   D
```

However we have the B and C git repos set up with D as a submodule. we would like to setup B and C as submodules in A, but we would also like to somehow have them both point to a single submodule instance of D.

Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you add B and C as submodules to A, their .git files will be stored in A under .git/modules/B and .git/modules/C. Each of those (once you've done `git submodule init; git submodule update` in each) will have its own .git/modules/D, however, so the repo files will not be shared. Each will have its own checked-out copy of the files as well.

You could get around these issues with symlinks. For example, you could add D as a submodule only to B, then symlink B's D in C. Now you can work in either B/D or C/D, and the other will stay in sync. There are 2 problems with this, though. The first is that you can't check out different points in each - they must stay in sync, because they're the same thing. This is minor, though, and may even match your wishes. The second is worse; if you're tracking D only in B, and C is 'tracking' it only as via symlink to B's D (symlinks *are* understood by git, btw), then C has no way to govern its own dependency on D.

It's normal to make a change to a submodule and then check that change in the dependent, containing repo, but now you have to remember to jump into the other repo in the diamond and make sure *it* works, too (automated testing - especially if run through a git hook - can help a lot here). If you revert a commit in B/D, e.g., or check out an older one, or switch branches in B/D, you have to always hop over to C/D and make sure things still work there. This setup can become a bit of a micromanagement pain, prone to broken commits, wherein B works against the current D, but C doesn't, or vice-versa.